# Function returning values between 0 and 1

Tags: calculus, limits

I need a function for weighting options based on how far they are from the value of the average for all the options in the set. 
The function should return a value between 0 and 1 and also return the average, when x = average. 
X can only be between 0 and infinity.

Something like this (where C = the average weight for the set of options)

$\;-x \to 0, y\to  0\\-x=C, y=C\\-x\to{\sim},y\to 1$

I've looked at something like $1-\frac{1}{1-x}$, but that only works for the first and third requirement.

Comment: If the function must return something in $[0,1]$ and the average is outside this set, then of course the second requirement cannot be met.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I think that in that case the function should return 0.5

Comment: Indeed, the conditions are a bit strange. If $c=1$, what should happen? The last requirement is that the function should approach 1 (from below?), so how can that be in the case $c=1$ (or close to $1$)?

Comment: If we don't take the last condition into account, one thing that we could use is something like
$$
f(x) = \frac{1 - \frac{1}{cx+1}}{1- \frac{1}{c^2 + 1}} c
$$
I didn't simplify the expression yet, but this is what I was experimenting with. You can take the factor $c$ out also, if you need ...

Comment: The average, C, is always between 1 and 0 as well, i.e. within the boundaries. When C = 1, then if X=1, Y=1. If C = 0,2, then when X=0,2, Y=0,2 etc.

Comment: What do you require of your function in terms of smoothness? You can do piecewise.

Comment: Okay I have a suggestion that fulfills the requirements:
$$
f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
x,& \text{if}~x\leq c \\
1-Ae^{kx} , & \text{if}~ x > c
\end{array}
\right.
$$
and then you set $k = \frac{1}{c-1}$ and $A = \frac{1-c}{e^{kc}}$. Try if this works out.

Answer (score 2):

What choice of $f$ would satisfy $f(x)=0,\,f(C)=C,\,f(\infty)=1$ if $C\in(0,\,1)$? With $f(x)=xg(x)$ it suffices for $g(0)$ to be finite, for $g(C)$ to equal $1$, and for $g(x)\sim\frac1x$ for large $x>0$. For example, $g(x)=\frac{1}{x+1-C}$ works.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the statement of the problem needs some correction. If $x$ is the value between 0 and $\infty$ and $y$ should be between 0 and 1, you cannot map $x_{avg}\gt1$ to the same value of $y$.

The problem makes sense if you ask for something like this:

$$x = 0\implies y=0$$
$$x = x_{avg}=c\implies y=\frac12$$
$$x = \infty\implies y=1$$

In that case you are mapping domain $[0,\infty)$ onto domain $[0,1)$. A simple function like:

$$y=1-2^{-\frac{x}{c}}$$

...would serve for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $f(x) = 2/\pi \arctan(x)$, which fulfills conditions $1$ and $3$, as a baseline. Some scaling on the $x$-axis should take care of it, that is, $g(x) = f(\alpha x)$ should work for some $\alpha$.

Indeed, we need $g(c) = c \iff \arctan(\alpha c) = c\pi/2$.
So that $ \alpha = \frac1c\tan(c\pi/2)$ should work well enough.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out your answer and I will try to answer you in parts.

*First condition*:

The the function should scale down a set of values of range $[0,\infty)$ to $[0,1]$.We can easily use some famous Fuzzy functions like  sigmoid($\sigma$) and$f(x)=\frac{2}{π}arctan(x)$  for doing so.Or to get a nearly uniform distribution you can choose x to be x−μ. If you want the maximum value to be nearly $1$ and/or minumum value to be nearly $0$ we you may also you a scaling factor along with it.


*Problem*:This function would scale down even the average so we need some variance to the pre-defined function  to get what we want.

We try defining it with some additional term $\frac{\mu}{e^{c(x-\mu)}} +\frac{2}{\pi}arctan(|x-\mu|)$ where $c-> \infty$ or you can use any very big number for practical calculations.
You can tweak the functionality by adding some scaling factors to the input and output depending on the output you want 
*One thing to keep in  mind -  $ \mu$ should not be comparable to infinity.*

Answer (score 0):

Take a function growing from the origin, with an horizontal asymptote, such as $1-e^{-x}$ and solve

$$1-e^x=c,$$ which gives $x=\log(1-c)$.

Then by rescaling the variable,

$$y=1-e^{x\log(1-c)/c}$$ does the trick.

Other options: $\dfrac{2\arctan x}\pi, \tanh x, \dfrac x{1+x},\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1},\cdots$